# Show specific data to a user after log in

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using simple membership provider and mvc. After a user registers he/she will be redirected to a view called registerDepartments. Incase time is an issue the user can login at a later stage. How do I retrieve the data registered by the user previously. In my previous workings it shows all the data from the table for all users who registered a branch.

Comment: Please add code so we can help further

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question clearly, because you didn't show any code of your work and any example.

However I think you want to retrieve branches created by a user for him/her right? If So, you can use something like the following:

```
var currentUserId = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
var branches = dbCtx.Branches
    .Where(b => b.CreatorUserId == currentUserId).ToList();
```